# Adding an Windows 7 Explorer indexable custom property to an excel file

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a folder full of Excel files which are customer invoices. Each morning I check my bank, find amounts that have been paid into my account and then do a search in the invoice folder to find an invoice which matches this amount.

To make it easier to find the correct invoice I created a custom property in Excel('total') and linked it(via File->Info->Properties(dropdown)->Custom) to the correct content source.

In the properties box in the custom dialog box, the Value field is updated properly.

The problem is I can't see or search this value from Windows Explorer. I would like to open the folder in Explorer and then use the search on the top right to type in "total:100" and have the matching files shown. Or at least a new column here for this custom property.